# Is an SQL database more memory/performance efficient than a large Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas

I have more than 6000 XML want to parse and save as csv (or anything else for storage).

I need to perform JOIN for each XML to join them to big dataframe.

The problem is the process takes so long and uses too many memory.

I am wondering would sql can solve the problem? faster and less memory consumption?

```
def get_data(lst):
    results = pd.DataFrame()
    errors = []

    for data in lst:
        try:
            df = parseXML_Annual(data)
            try:
                results = results.join(df, how = "outer")
            except:
                results = df
        except:
            errors.append(data)

    return results, errors

results, errors = get_data(lst_result)
```

Comment: Do you mean 6000 files on the disk? How big is your data frame? Is that 1 time thing, or some regular job?

Comment: I get the 6000 files through API. And store all the xml string into a list. Then loop through the list to get them parsed.

As I am doing an outer join, the dataframe can go a bit large. The columns will be 6000. The rows, maybe 1000 something. I am not sure.

It is a regular job.

Comment: OK, so each XML is basically 2 column table right? 6K column table doesn't sounds like a good idea for SQL, I would try to tune the code. Check which part is slowing down the process the most, is it XML parsing or joining. Run same loop for each part separately.

Comment: I am trying to download financial statement information. Each XML represents one company, and it has 5 years of data of different fields. Then, I want to join each company together with index equals to all the fields, and columns equal to the company.

Parse Data should be fast. I guess the problem is the JOIN becoz not every xml shares the same index, so, the dataframe may be very large.

Comment: Maybe something like thishttps://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83951/financial-database-design

Comment: In your code example, I don't see what are you joining those table on (no "on" parameter"). You might do some unexpected many to many join, say if you join on company, and same company appear in both tables 3 times you'll get 9 rows  in the output.  I would also check how that script works on smaller arrays. Say if on 1000 files it runs for a minute but for 2000 it runs way much longer (like 20 minutes), there might be an issue with memory handling

Comment: If you want to do this in relational database, I guess you'd need to have either 6000 tables or table with 6K columns. It sounds crazy ) Even if you can do this it's kind of hard to interact with that, although it depends on what you going to do with this data. After that 1000X6000 data structure is created, what are you going to do with that?

Comment: This is the typical XML: https://drive.google.com/file/d/169bPi-Hph21YbPV4IutCuJaIJz5pXlFg/view?usp=sharing

and I have >6000 files. My originally plan was to join the annual report together, so that I can filter companies from the dataframe which fulfill my criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your sample, entire XML file is related to the same company. To me it sounds that you need to add this a new row, not join it as a table. In my understanding you want to have some list of metrics for each company. If so you probably can just stick with key-value storage. If python is your primary tool, use dictionary, and then save it as a JSON file.
In your for loop just fill a blank dictionary with data from XML like this:

```
report = {

"apple": {
    'metricSet1': {"m11": 5, "m12": 2, "m13": 3},
    'metricSet2': {"m21": 4, "m22": 5, "m23": 6}
},

"google": {
    'metricSet1': {"m11": 1, "m12": 13, "m13": 3},
    'metricSet2': {"m21": 9, "m22": 0, "m23": 11}
},

"facebook": {
    'metricSet1': {"m11": 1, "m12": 9, "m13": 9},
    'metricSet2': {"m21": 7, "m22": 2, "m23": 4}
}
```

}

when you need to query it or fill some table with data do something like this:

```
for k in report.keys():
row = [
    k,
    report[k]["metricSet1"]["m12"],
    report[k]["metricSet2"]["m22"],
    report[k]["metricSet2"]["m23"]
]
print(row)
```

If data structure is not changing (say all these XML are the same) it would make sence to store it in SQL database, creating a table for each metric set. If XML structure may vary then just keep it as json file, or probably in some Key-Value based database, like mongo